# How do I get a rt2800usb wireless device working?

Tags: networking, wireless, 13.04, network-manager

My brand new desktop running 13.04 has endless problems with wireless. Dozens of others are flooding forums with reports of the same problems.

It worked fine for a few days, then there were a few days where it started having problems sometimes and working sometimes. Now it never works at all.

I have 5+ devices all able to connect without any trouble at all, including iPhone, Android phone, 3DS, multiple game consoles, a laptop running windows 7, and even a second desktop machine running Ubuntu 12.04 sitting right behind the 13.04 machine. All other devices have full wireless bars displayed (strong signals).

At any moment, one of the following is happening, and it changes randomly:

- Trying to connect forever, but never establishing a connection.
  Wireless icon constantly animating.
- Finds no wireless networks at all. (There are 12+ in range according to other devices.)
- Will not try to connect to the network. If I use the icon to connect, it will
  display "Disconnected" within a few seconds.
- Will continuously ask for the network password. Typing it in correctly does not help.
- Wireless is working fine. This happens sometimes. It can work for days at a time, or only 10 mins at a time.

Various things that usually do nothing but sometimes fix the problem:

- Reboot. This has the best chance of helping, but it usually takes 5+ times.
- Disable/re-enable Wi-Fi using the wireless icon.
- Disable/re-enable Networking using the wireless icon.
- Use the icon to try and connect to a network (if found).
- Use the icon to open Edit Connections and delete my connection info, causing it to be recreated (once it's actually found again).

Various things that seem to make no difference:

- Changing between using Linux headers in grub at bootup, between 3.10.0, 3.9.0, or 3.8.0.
- Move the wireless router very close to the desktop.
- Running `sudo rfkill unblock all` (I dunno what this is supposed to do.)

I've used Ubuntu for 6 years and I've never had a problem with networking. Now I'm spending all my time reading through endless problem reports and trying all the answers. None of them have helped. I am doing this instead of getting work done, which is defeating the whole purpose of using Ubuntu. It's heartbreaking to be honest.

In the current state of "no networks are showing up", here are outputs from the random things that other people are usually asked to run:

**lspic**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
```

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
e100                   41119  0 
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
parport_pc             28284  0 
ppdev                  17106  0 
bnep                   18258  2 
rfcomm                 47863  12 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
arc4                   12573  2 
rt2800usb              27201  0 
rt2x00usb              20857  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              68029  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              55764  3 rt2x00usb,rt2800lib,rt2800usb
coretemp               13596  0 
mac80211              656164  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb,rt2800lib
kvm_intel             138733  0 
kvm                   452835  1 kvm_intel
cfg80211              547224  2 mac80211,rt2x00lib
crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib
ghash_clmulni_intel    13259  0 
aesni_intel            55449  0 
usb_storage            61749  1 
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
joydev                 17613  0 
xts                    12922  1 aesni_intel
nouveau              1001310  3 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     37407  1 
lrw                    13294  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  2 lrw,xts
mxm_wmi                13021  1 nouveau
snd_hda_codec_realtek    46511  1 
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
wmi                    19256  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
snd_hda_intel          44397  5 
ttm                    88251  1 nouveau
drm_kms_helper         49082  1 nouveau
drm                   295908  5 ttm,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
snd_hda_codec         190010  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
cryptd                 20501  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_hwdep              13613  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102477  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
btusb                  18291  0 
snd_page_alloc         18798  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13564  1 nouveau
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30417  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61930  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
bluetooth             251354  22 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                17060  0 
snd_timer              29989  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
mei                    46588  0 
snd                    69533  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
psmouse                97838  0 
microcode              22923  0 
soundcore              12680  1 snd
video                  19467  1 nouveau
mac_hid                13253  0 
serio_raw              13215  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 47346  0 
hid                   101248  2 hid_generic,usbhid
ahci                   30063  3 
libahci                32088  1 ahci
e1000e                207005  0 
ptp                    18668  1 e1000e
pps_core               14080  1 ptp
```

**sudo lshw -c network**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 [GeForce GT 610] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GF119 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 03)
```

**sudo iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

**sudo iwlist scan**

```
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     No scan results
```

**NOTE:** This dmesg was done after a reboot where the network manager was continuously displaying the "disconnected" message over and over. So it must have been trying to connect at this time. My network was displayed in the list of options, as the only option despite other devices picking up 12+ access points. The router channel is set to auto.

**dmesg | tail -30**

```
[  187.418446] wlan0: associated
[  190.405601] wlan0: disassociated from 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 (Reason: 15)
[  190.443312] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  190.443431] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 by local choice (reason=3)
[  190.451635] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  190.451643] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  190.451648] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  190.451652] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  190.451656] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  190.451659] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  190.451662] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  191.824451] wlan0: authenticate with 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44
[  191.850608] wlan0: send auth to 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 (try 1/3)
[  191.884604] wlan0: send auth to 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 (try 2/3)
[  191.886309] wlan0: authenticated
[  191.886579] rt2800usb 3-5.3:1.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  191.886588] rt2800usb 3-5.3:1.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  191.889556] wlan0: associate with 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 (try 1/3)
[  192.001493] wlan0: associate with 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 (try 2/3)
[  192.040274] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=3)
[  192.044235] wlan0: associated
[  193.948188] wlan0: deauthenticating from 00:14:d1:a8:c3:44 by local choice (reason=3)
[  193.981501] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  193.984080] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  193.984082] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  193.984084] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  193.984085] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  193.984085] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  193.984086] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  193.984087] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
```

The router uses MAC filtering, and security is WPA PSK with cipher as auto.

So, any ideas? Or is the solution just to not use 13.04 unless you have a wired connection? (I don't have this option.) If so, please just tell me straight. I survived 9.04 Jaunty, and I can survive 13.04 Raring.

***Update #1***

Results from trying Wild Man's first answer:

```
jii@conan:~$ echo "options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf
options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=y

jii@conan:~$ sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800usb 
rmmod rt2800usb
rmmod rt2800lib
rmmod crc_ccitt
rmmod rt2x00usb
rmmod rt2x00lib
rmmod mac80211
rmmod cfg80211

jii@conan:~$ sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/lib/crc-ccitt.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/3.10.0-031000-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko nohwcrypt=y
```

I tried:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

but I didn't have the package. It said to install gksu. I tried that, but of course, not having Internet, I didn't get the package.

So instead I did:

```
sudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

Which created the file. Here is the body:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

I then rebooted. No change. I tried adding exit 0 to the bottom of the wireless file, and rebooted. No change. Please note that this is a desktop machine. I'm assuming power management is primarily for laptops, but the iwconfig does state that power management is on, so who knows.

The recommended router changes I did not do, since the current router settings are (I think) required for some of the older devices I have, and because the current settings work on all my modern devices including Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. I do appreciate the advice though, and I'll look into it when I have time.

Anything else to try?

***Update #2***

I booted into Ubuntu 12.04.3 from a dvd, and the same problems exist.

I have a separate old desktop machine with 12.04 installed that has no wireless problems at all. So obviously the problem is wireless hardware compatibility in both 12.04.03 LTS and 13.04.

***Update #3***

The same problems exist even when using a wired connection. I plugged an ethernet cable directly to the router and the network manager added an "Auto Ethernet" entry, but it cannot establish a connection to it. So the problem is not specific to wireless.

Meanwhile, I purchased a Trendnet N300 wireless USB adapter, TEW-664UB. I plugged it in, but I have no idea how to get Ubuntu to try and use it. Can anyone tell me how? Can I download a package  on another computer and copy the .deb over to do an install, etc?

I'm installing windows 7 to double check that the internet connection works there and it's not just some magically faulty hardware.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Please copy and paste one line at a time for accuracy:

```
echo "options rt2800usb nohwcrypt=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800usb.conf 

sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800usb 

sudo modprobe -v rt2800usb
```

watch for errors.
Then:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/pm/power.d/wireless
```

(this will create or edit a configuration file that will override the default power management behavior) and enter the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

above exit0, then save gedit, close.

This error message is in dmesg "disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP" I recommend going into your router and changing that to disabled.

Also set your encryption while in the router settings to wpa2 only if you have that option.

If you change encryption to wpa2 you will need to go into network manger in the top right corner of the screen by clicking on the internet icon, then go to edit connections>wireless and change security settings to wpa/wpa2 and reboot.
Thanks

Comment: I tried your suggestions and updated the post. It seemed to have no change.

Comment: It is safe to run it was written by me and some good friends it will help diagnose your wireless issue.
Paste this command in a terminal  `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script` 
It will download a script and create a file named (wireless-info.txt, or wireless-info.txt.tar.gz) in your home folder paste the file here http://pastebin.com/ then paste the link back here.